# Explanation of $n$-th order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, intuition

To be more formal, an $n$th order ordinary differential equation for a function y(t) is an equation of the form $F(d^ny/dt^n , d^{n−1}y/dt^{n−1} ,...,dy/dt , y,t)= 0$. (3.4) (Of course we want $d^ny/dt^n$ to occur in $F$;if$F(¨y, ˙y, y,t) $is $y − t$ then the resulting equation  $(y − t = 0)$ is not a differential equation at all.) If t does not occur explicitly in the equation, as in $dy/dt = f(y)$, then the equation is said to be autonomous.

So what does $F(d^ny/dt^n , d^n−1y/dt^n−1 ,...,dy/dt , y,t)= 0$ mean. Is $F$ a function? What does it mean since it is mentioned nowhere in book.Can someone give an intutive explanation?

Comment: $$F(y^{(n)},y^{(n-1)},\cdots y',y,t)=0$$ establishes an *implicit* relation between the derivatives and the independent variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $F$ is a function.  Here's a typical example: the differential equation

$$t \dfrac{d^2 y}{dt^2} + y \dfrac{dy}{dt} + 1 = 0$$

This is $F \left(\dfrac{d^2 y}{dt^2}, \dfrac{dy}{dt}, y, t\right) = 0$ where 
$F(a,b,y,t) = t a + y b + 1$.

Comment: so the place where you write "where" can I interpret that as "in this case"? Because I don't think function $F$ has any absolute definition.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "where".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually, this is a function $F : \overbrace{\mathbb{R}^m \times\cdots \times \mathbb{R}^m}^{n+1 \text{ times }} \times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^m$, or at least defined on a subset. Here, $y$ is a vector of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Ok. Indulge me.For a moment Pretend that I am an idiot. And give an informal intutive explanation that what it actually means I mean whole definition in more humanistic way.

Comment: For example, if $F(a,b,c,t) = a^2 + bt + c*a/t$ the equation will be $(y'')^2 + y'*t + y*y''/t = 0$

Comment: so @Dldier_ this doesn't actually give any information about equation except what derivative and variable is involved right? The equation is defined by us.

Comment: Basically, any function $F$ gives a differential equation. There are plenty of them, and there is no common way to look at them, except for exceptional cases like linear, homogeneous, etc. So yeah, this is the general case :/